# How do I create a perfectly seamless loop gif from a video which has multiple cycles?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, editing, gif

Let's say for example I have a video of a ball going around in a circle. In the video, it's obvious it is a loop and the entire video is around 1 minute and 20 seconds long, so the ball goes around the circle for multiple times. I want to create a gif of it so that the entire gif is the ball going around the circle just one time (that's the point of a gif). The problem is, because the video shows the ball going around the circle multiple times, online "Seamless loop creators" or "Perfect loop creators" softwares do not work as they put multiple cycles into the gif, producing a 200mb gif file. This is very inefficient.

Of course, I can use a video editor and go frame by frame to find the time where the ball is the highest, cut there, find the next time where the ball is the highest and cut there, producing the shortest perfect gif. But the ball around the circle is just an example and the actual video problem I have is rain so it is visually impossible to determine the time duration of each cycle, or how many complete cycles are in the video, or when the cycle repeats, etc.

Maybe is there a way to do this with FFMPEG or any cool packages/tools that does this? I use Davinci Resolve for the editor so if there's any (free) plugin in there that might be helpful, please help me.

Comment: I'd be tempted to cut by hand to just over one cycle, then send the result to the loop creator. Unless there's a loop creator that you can set hints first, I don't see any automated process is going to find just one loop out of many.

Comment: Hello, this is better suited at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: @Tetsujin The problem is, I do not know how long one cycle is. I can guess but I'm worried the resulting gif will have more than one cycle. Again, because it's a video of rain, it's very difficult to guess. Also, the websites I mentioned work like this: First, take the first frame, then compare it with the last frame, then with the second last frame, third last frame, and continue from the end until it finds a match, then it will cut there. I want the same automated task but instead of starting from the end of the long video, start from the start of the video (second frame) and continue forwar

Comment: Yeah, I get the idea, and for a simple loop that's a reasonable way to tackle it. Of course, it falls down as soon as the loop isn't simple. Because what you have isn't likely a very common task, maybe no-one thought of it as yet. It might be worth poking one of the developers of one of these structures & ask them if they could code a 'reverse' option, that would start from frame 2 & advance.

Comment: Anecdotally, this feels very similar to my 'day job' in the 90s; we were making sample sets for keyboards/synthesizers, trying to keep the memory as small as possible. We had to take the attack portion of, say, a piano note, then find the first point you could generate a seamless loop. We had software built to aid us in this, but there was a lot of skill, judgment and a whole lot of tedious repetition, manually dragging start & end points, day in, day out, to find the best loop ;)

Comment: Just a thought... Assuming you have an idea of the approx length of the loops. Extracting a clip that contains at least one loop, you could then convert the frames to images with ffmpeg,  then put these through an app like Visipics. This will show the duplicates, and more importantly, how many frames per loop. And where a loop starts and ends. Not automated as such,  but some of the grind is taken out of the task.